# jquery get checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to get the list of checkboxes and the count that are checked. I have this:

```
        var obj = $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox');

        var childCount=$(obj).size();
        var checkedCount=$(obj).(':checked').length;
```

I get error on checkedCount

??

Comment: read this http://forum.jquery.com/topic/count-checked-checkboxes

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```
    var obj = $(this).closest('li').find(':checkbox');

    var childCount = obj.size();
    var checkedCount =  obj.filter(':checked').length;
```

> **filter**
>   Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Also, you don't need to wrap `obj` with `$()`, because it's already a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

to get checked checkboxes length :

```
$('input[name^="complete"]:checked').length;
```

to get unchecked checkboxes length :

```
$('input[name^="complete"]:unchecked').length;
```

where `"complete"` is a name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo .. you can't do $('#foo').() .. you need:

```
$('#foo').filter(':checkbox')
```

filter selector - http://api.jquery.com/filter